# Found selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

**Action:**
Entering password

**Code(Selenium with Python):**

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//input[@id='passwordClear1']").send_keys("TPtp123#")
```

**Source Code:**

```
    ..input type="text" style="display: block;" autocomplete="OFF" maxlength="20" onclick="if (this.value == 'Password') { this.value = ''; }" onblur="if (this.value == '') { this.value = 'Password'; }" value="Password" name="passwordClear" id="passwordClear1" class="txtbox disblk font13 fleft" onfocus="passwordInput1();" tabindex="1"> <input type="password" style="display: none;" autocomplete="OFF" maxlength="20" value="" id="password1" name="password" class="txtbox disnon fleft" onblur="changeInput1();">
    ..input type="submit" value="Login" onclick="PDLogTrackAjax();" class="medimum-btn login-btn font14 fleft" style="border:0px; height:36px; margin-left:8px;" tabindex="0"><br clear="all">
```

**Error:**

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable
```

**Please help me for resolving this error.**

Answer (score 0):

You got to use `JavascriptExecutor`.
You can use `JavascriptExecutor js=(JavascriptExecutor)driver`
and Execute the script as the locator contains ajax element.